# Blank windows with documentation examples of Gtk(0.17) (julia 1.1)

Tags: gtk, julia

I got an issue with Gtk.
My code is compiling with no error, but only the windows with its title is appearing.

So I wondered if I made something wrong and tried some examples of the documentation (see below).
And it didn't worked either.

I updated the packages, rm, and add again, no error. 
No error in compiling, nothing.

When I ask if the widgets are visible it is saying yes.

I saw that it could be a configuration problem of gtk but with no more explanation.

Thank you for your help !

```
using Gtk

ls = GtkListStore(String, Int, Bool, Bool)
push!(ls,("Peter",20,false,true))
push!(ls,("Paul",30,false,true))
push!(ls,("Mary",25,true,true))
insert!(ls, 2, ("Susanne",35,true,true))

rTxt = GtkCellRendererText()
rTog = GtkCellRendererToggle()

c1 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Name", rTxt, Dict([("text",0)]), sort_column_id=0)
c2 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Age", rTxt, Dict([("text",1)]), sort_column_id=1)
c3 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Female", rTog, Dict([("active",2)]), sort_column_id=2)

tmFiltered = GtkTreeModelFilter(ls)
GAccessor.visible_column(tmFiltered,3)
tv = GtkTreeView(GtkTreeModel(tmFiltered))
push!(tv, c1, c2, c3)

selection = GAccessor.selection(tv)

signal_connect(selection, "changed") do widget
  if hasselection(selection)
    currentIt = selected(selection)

    println("Name: ", GtkTreeModel(tmFiltered)[currentIt,1],
            " Age: ", GtkTreeModel(tmFiltered)[currentIt,1])
  end
end

ent = GtkEntry()

signal_connect(ent, "changed") do widget
  searchText = get_gtk_property(ent, :text, String)

  for l=1:length(ls)
    showMe = true

    if length(searchText) > 0
      showMe = showMe && occursin(lowercase(searchText), lowercase(ls[l,1]))
    end

    ls[l,4] = showMe
  end
end

vbox = GtkBox(:v)
push!(vbox,ent,tv)

win = GtkWindow(vbox, "List View with Filter")
showall(win)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, but run as a file, your app closes so fast you do not see it display at all.  This is covered in the Gtk.jl docs under "Non REPL Usage" ie running as a file, outside the julia REPL command line. Just replace showall(win) with:

```
condition = Condition()
endit(w) = notify(condition)
signal_connect(endit, win, :destroy)
showall(win)
wait(condition)
```

The app will then pass control to the internal Gtk runtime event loop and wait for the app to close. I was able to run your app and see the check boxes fine with this. If you cannot, you might have a problem with your local files.